# Building a Security System using Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, streaming

I have a spare USB webcam at home and I plan to order a Raspberry Pi Model B which will capture video and stream it live. This will be my first time handling a Raspberry Pi. Before oredring the Raspberry Pi, I just wanted to confirm that this is infact possible and that the Raspberry Pi Model B will suffice for the task or I need to order a higher spec board. Any information would be hugely helpful

Thanks

Comment: That obviously depends on the frame rate and resolution of the video stream as well as the treatment you want to apply to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont mind running a low frame rate and low resolution streaming as it is only an experimentation. I just want to know if it can work with just 512 MB memory and no transcoding applied.

Comment: I'll let more experienced users answer this, but based on the hardware I saw in some IP cameras, even their 400Mhz CPU and 64MB or RAM is enough to serve a 640x480 image at 25 FPS, so I'm pretty sure your Raspberry will be more than enough.

Comment: see also [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about video streaming requirements in low-powered devices.

Comment: If you only work is capture and stream video I suggest you buy cheap xiaomi IP camera which can hack and install RTSP server and it will do the work for you without any other setup. It's cheaper than Raspberry pi and  quality is very high compared to other cheap cameras. The model I have is Xiaofang 1s. you can search github Dafang hacks for how to install custom firmware